# zsh: A prefix function that runs the rest of the line with no alias expansion

Tags: zsh, eval

I am thinking of:

```
function noalias() { 
  setopt localoptions noexpandalias
  "$@"
 }
```

But I don't know what the last line should be. `eval "${*:q}"`? `eval "$@"`? `eval "${@:q}"`? `"${@:q}"`? `${@:q}`? `$@`? (could you explain the differences between these? )

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are expanded at a very early stage, before  a simple command is understood as such let alone a function is executed, so that can't work.

You need the `noaliases` (`expandalias` is the `bash` option) option to be in effect before the command line is read and parsed.

However, if you want to disable only normal aliases, that is the ones expanded in command position defined with `alias foo=bar`, doing:

```
noalias() "$@"
```

is enough, because if there's an alias for `cmd`, it wouldn't be expanded in:

```
noalias cmd args
```

Because `cmd` is not  in command position.

That wouldn't work for *global* aliases though (the ones set with `alias -g`, like `alias -g args=foo` than expand any shell *word* whether they are in command position or not).

Even if you did:

```
noalias() { 
  setopt localoptions noaliases
  eval "$@"
}
```

And invoke your command with:

```
noalias 'cmd args'
```

That would not be foolproof, for instance after:

```
alias -g "'cmd arg'=gotcha"
```

or

```
alias -g noalias=gotcha
```

You'd need to run

```
set +o expandalias
```

Before the command is read. You could do it with a key  binding though:

```
toggle-aliases() {
  if [[ -o aliases ]]; then
    set +o aliases
  else
    set -o aliases
  fi
  zle -I
}
zle -N toggle-aliases
bindkey '\eA' toggle-aliases
PS1='[aliases $options[aliases]] '$PS1
```

And press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to toggle.

Comment: Hmm. But `noalias '...'` does work if there is no malicious intent, right? What's the difference between `$@` and `eval "$@"`?

Comment: @HappyFace, `eval` evaluates the text that's made of the concatenation of the positional parameters as shell code, `"$@"` runs the command whose name is stored in `$1` with all the positional parameters as argument. There's no evaluation of shell code there (`$@` without quotes should never be used, though it's not as bad in `zsh` as in other shells, it  only drops the empty elements there)